# Pergunta com recompensa não obteve novas respostas

Tags: debate

A um tempo atrás eu havia [feito uma pergunta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246817/calcular-frete-dos-correios-para-diversos-produtos) no SOPT, obtive uma resposta mas foi muito teórica, não respondeu de fato minha dúvida nem deu uma orientação muito boa (na minha opinião).

Recentemente então, para tentar obter uma resposta satisfatória, criei uma recompensa para a pergunta. A recompensa está se encerrando hoje e não houve nenhuma nova resposta, ou seja, não consegui obter o resultado para minha dúvida.

Mas agora recebi uma notificação dizendo que devo dar a reputação para uma das resposta, nesse caso, apenas uma (que já existia ante do início da reputação). Mas não é isso que desejo, pois ainda assim não resolveu o problema.

O que posso/devo fazer nesse caso?

Comment: É só não dar a recompensa pra ela. De qualquer forma, ela tem 11 votos, acho que isso é suficiente para o sistema atribuir metade da reputação para a resposta.

Comment: @LINQ pois é, mas eu recebi notificação informando que teria que escolher uma resposta. Se não escolher, os pontos retornam para mim então?

Comment: Não, eles nunca voltam pra você. Ou o sistema vai atribuir 50% à resposta do JeffersonQuesado ou ele não vai fazer nada.

Comment: E 50% seria jogado fora. Depois pode tentar de novo, quem outra pessoa aparece pra responder. Eu tentaria, mas faltando alguns minutos nem vou fazer porque é improvável que dê para responder bem nesse tempo. Se bem que parece que a resposta é boa e não dá para fazer muito melhor que isso, a pergunta é tão teórica quanto a resposta, que achei até mais pra´toca do que poderia ser.

Comment: @Maniero Entendi. Bom, sobre a questão, eu ainda tenho 24horas para aplicar a recompensa. Se você quiser dar uma resposta, agradeço.

Comment: Minha ideia na resposta era mostrar a dificuldade de empacotamento 2D. É algo que você precisa levar em consideração ao montar um pacote. E também tem o ponto de que diferentes montagens, com o mesmo volume, poder ser precificada de modo distinto. Tentei contribuir para mostrar que ideias mais _naïve_ não dariam a resposta correta

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim sim, eu entendi sua resposta (até fiquei aguardando, já que você comentou que tentaria elaborar uma para 3D). Minha ideia com a recompensa foi de tentar obter uma resposta mais completa (com exemplos de códigos de como fazer isso), não no sentido de que sua resposta foi ruim, apenas não cobriu o problema 100%. Mas lógico, eu também sei que é um tópico difícil de abordar pois envolve muitas variáveis.

Comment: Eu realmente devo admitir que tinha esquecido. Dentre diversas respostas, infelizmente acaba que eu deixo uma ou outra ponta sem terminar por considerar útil o suficiente a resposta. Mas se eu disse que vou terminar, eu vou terminar. Talvez daqui a alguns anos, rsrs. Mas no estado atual não estou digno de receber a recompensa, admito

Comment: Celso, estou um pouco em duvida, a sua pergunta é sobre o que fazer com os pontos, ou sobre como conseguir melhores resultados em situações assim?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento se entendi bem sua questão, acho que é um pouco dos dois, pois o serviço dos correios não tem, por exemplo, um campo "produto2", "produto3", etc.. Mas eu fiz uma resposta agora na questão onde acho que consegui atingir um bom resultado para o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR: qualquer resposta melhor que a do Jefferson provavelmente seria uma tese de mestrado de Ciência da Computação.

> obtive uma resposta mas foi muito teórica, não respondeu de fato minha dúvida nem deu uma orientação muito boa

O Jefferson explicou em termos leigos [o problema da mochila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila). Infelizmente para você esse problema é [NP-completo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completo). O assunto é extenso, mas pra resumir:

- Não existe solução simples para o seu problema. Isso não é uma opinião, é um fato - vide a Wiki linkada acima. Seria mais fácil calcular o PI até a última casa decimal;
- Se existisse solução simples, diversos outros problemas computacionais seriam resolvidos pela mesma solução. O descobridor da solução seria um candidato de peso para um prêmio Nobel em economia;
- Existem [heurísticas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heur%C3%ADstica) para isso, mas nenhuma é perfeita e elas em geral são desenvolvidas para casos específicos.

Se você quer ignorar a parte matemática da coisa e resolver o seu problema logo, suas melhores chances seriam começar a desenvolver sua própria heurística, ou tentar fazer engenharia reversa das [soluções disponíveis em repositórios públicos](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=knapsack+problem&type=). Infelizmente esse último caso é um jogo de tentativa-e-erro aliada à sorte, já que não há garantias de que um algoritmo qualquer desses realmente vá resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Entendi. É, realmente eu já imaginava que algo dessa magnitude não fosse simples de conseguir. Depois de muito pesquisar eu fiz minha própria resposta na questão onde acho que consegui atingir um bom resultado.